# Is the shortness of boron trifluoride's bonds better understood and explained now than it was "way back" in the 20th century?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, bond, hybridization

Wikipedia's [Boron trifluoride; Structure and bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boron_trifluoride#Structure_and_bonding) says:

> In the boron trihalides, BX3, the length of the B–X bonds (1.30 Å) is shorter than would be expected for single bonds,<sup>7</sup> and this shortness may indicate stronger B–X [π-bonding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_bond) in the fluoride. **A facile explanation** invokes the symmetry-allowed overlap of a p orbital on the boron atom with the in-phase combination of the three similarly oriented p orbitals on fluorine atoms.<sup>7</sup> **Others point to** the ionic nature of the bonds in BF3.<sup>8</sup>
>
> <sup>7</sup> *Chemistry of the Elements* N. N. Greenwood, A. Earnshaw, Elsevier (1997)
>
> <sup>8</sup>Gillespie, Ronald J. (1998). "[Covalent and Ionic Molecules: Why Are BeF2 and AlF3 High Melting Point Solids whereas BF3 and SiF4 Are Gases?](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed075p923)". Journal of Chemical Education. 75 (7): 923.

Google's English dictionary uses [Oxford languages](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/) and gives the following definition and synonym for "facile":

> *adj* ignoring the true complexities of an issue; superficial. "facile generalizations"
>
> Similar: simplistic, superficial, oversimple, oversimplified, schematic

I also noticed that the references cited are from 1997 and 1998 and in the subsequent near-quarter-century quantum-mechanical computational techniques have improved substantially. So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Is the shortness of boron trifluoride's bonds better understood and explained now than it was "way back" in the 20th century?

Comment: I guess the disappointing answer to your question is: No. Look up charge-shift bond and see for yourself if that makes understanding and explaining easier. || @Tyberius You've linked to the same post twice; I can only guess that this was not intended.

Comment: [Semi-related post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34842/why-is-bcl3-a-monomer-whereas-alcl3-exists-as-a-dimer) about BCl3 dimerization that touches on the bond lengths. Also, a [much earlier study](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0009261473802179) linked in the comments about simulating the BF3 with ab initio methods.